# CakePHP caching elements with duration

Tags: php, cakephp, element, cakephp-2.0

Regarding to [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#caching-elements) we can cache elements like this:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', array(), array('cache' => true));
```

Caching with configuration is like this:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', array(),
    array('cache' => array('config' => 'view_long') );
```

How can I cache elements without predefined configuration ? How can I cache duration to elements? I tried this, but didn't work:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox',  array(),
     array('cache' => array('time' => '+30 minutes')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [configure cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class) in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Cache::config('hour', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

Cache::config('week', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

after this you can cache your element using defined configuration:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', array(), array('cache' => array('config' => 'week')));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Last line needs one more right parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only reference named cache configurations now, if you want to clear the cached element programmatically, you need to use Cache::delete() with the element name and key.

I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.echothis.com/2012/12/17/controlling-element-caching-in-cakephp-2-3/) about this.  There's also some more detail in [the relevant CakePHP forum thread](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/clear-element-cache-cakphp-2-0-td5123660.html).

(8/31/14) I haven't checked if this is still the behavior in CakePHP 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.